# How to change properties of dynamically created labels

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have created from an array several labels. In certain steps I have to change the x and y coordinate of the label, but don't know how to address the labels:

```
for zone in zoneArray {

        let zoneLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: locationX, y: locationY, width: 150, height: 75))

        zoneLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        zoneLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        zoneLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        zoneLabel.text = zone}
```

would be very happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could add a tag to every label and find the desired one using the tag itself...

```
var i = 1
for zone in zoneArray {
    let zoneLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: locationX, y: locationY, width: 150, height: 75))
    let zoneLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 75))
    zoneLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    zoneLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    zoneLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    zoneLabel.text = zone
    zoneLabel.tag = i
    i += 1 
}
```

Comment: Never set a view's tag to `0`. That's the default tag for all views and using it explicitly doesn't help you find that view.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick and helpful answers. Just one question to @DungeonDev : Is it also possible to have the tag as a string ? So I could use the 'zone' variable ? This would be more convenient for referring.

Comment: @Heki: I'm not sure what are you asking... but maybe you could create a subclass of UILabel and add a string property with the value you like.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to declare a UILabel array in your VC

```
var labels = [UILabel]()
```

And then append onto it inside of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps you need to consider while creating this type of label programmatically.

**Step 1:**

Make the label just like what Mr. Lou Franco said.

```
var labels = [UILabel]()
```

Step 2:

Do necessary coloring or texting.

**Important notes:** Do not set frame like what you did. Add constraint programmatically if you want to design it for all devices.That is,  use Auto-layout programmatically.

There are three approaches for doing auto-layout programmatically. But i love **Layout-anchoring** . Because it's easy.Just jump to it and you will love it.